# How to check programmatically that tomcat has authenticated the request?

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, servlets, webserver

I need to know in web server whether tomcat has authenticated the request or not. The way I used before and is suggested in the internet is to check whether the returned value of getUserPrincipal is null or not. In my case spring authentication may be configured, and if it's configured, but tomcat authentication isn't, getUserPrincipal will not return null.

Is there another way to programmatically know whether tomcat authentication is enabled or not?

Comment: Can Spring be configured to bind the user's principal to the request? Really, that should *always* be happening because the servlet spec says that "an authenticated login is synonymous with a principal being available on the request" (paraphrasing, [servlet 4.0](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf), section 13.3).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens. Tomcat authentication is disabled. I have a custom authentication class, which handles spring authentication. But in that class, I should know whether tomcat authenticated the request already or not.

Comment: i.e. I should do custom authentication in spring only if tomcat didn't do so already.

Comment: No... I'm suggesting that Spring should be configured to "massage" the request object such that it provides legitimate container-managed security. If it doesn't, many things will not work: principal checks (like yours), role-based checks, etc. Basically, no security settings in `web.xml` will work without that kind of binding.